# How do I change my photo in my message threads?

Tags: sms, profiles

I have an LG Optimus Elite and I am running the stock ROM.

In my text message threads, under "Me" where my messages are, it shows one of my contacts, rather than my Facebook or Google photo. How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't given your Android version, I shall give the steps I used for my device:

1. Open the messaging app.
2. Press your picture, or the standard picture.
3. An overlay should appear at the top. Click it, and select take picture or choose picture.
4. Crop picutre.
5. Restart the SMS app.

This video also shows it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hxULkTKe9E